# How to use mousewheel and scroll events properly in jquery?

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousewheel

my problem:

```
    if( user reach the bottom of the page){
      hide element;
    }else{
      show element;
    }
```

my solution is to use mousewheel / scroll  event handler  to know if the user is moving then calculate if I'm at the bottom of the page and hide or show an element...

everything works fine but i got this worning

> Handling of 'mousewheel' input event was delayed for 123 ms due to main thread being busy. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.

this ( I guess )  is due to the fact that this code

```
 jQuery('body').on('mousewheel', function(e){
```

runs too many times.

So  how can I make this code more efficient ?
Is there a way to run the event after the scroll?

I don't want to use plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using something like: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c709ym1s/)

```
    jQuery(window).on("scroll", function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight() == $(document).height())
        {
            //User reached end of page
            //Hide element here
            $("span").hide();
        }
        else
        {
            //Show element here
            $("span").show();
        }
   });
```